# Why does this JS return false for a non-integer?

Tags: javascript, types, casting, integer, return

Here is the code function from - the great [jQuery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/timeout.html)

```
function calculateTimeout(currElement, nextElement, opts, isForward) { 
var index = opts.currSlide; 
return index % 2 ? 2000 : false; 
}
```

I get what it does and its working fine the the last line I am curious about.

1. "return" obviously kills the function and returns what ever output it has
2. index is an variable set in the above line (is also an integer)
3. "% 2" then divides the index var by 2
4. Then the "? 2000 : false" is the short hand for if else and if the statement is true / false will return either 2000 or false.

So 3 will return true and 3.5 will return false for example.

So my question is why in this context does an integer return true but a non-integer return false?  I might have thought than any number would return true and 0 would return false?

Guessing it due to type casting but where is that set?

Thanks

Comment: `%` is the modulo operator. In the last line, the index is getting divided by two but it's the `remainder` that's being returned.

Comment: And in the case of 3.5 % 2, the result would be 1.5 which equates to false.

Comment: AH - I was reading that % as a /.  Couldn't see it for looking.  Makes sense now. Add your comment as an answer and I will accept.